# Will listing my major GPA instead of my cumulative GPA on my resume cause problems?

Tags: resume, human-resources, ethics, education

So I just started working in an admin position in a financial office and I think I may have slipped up. I listed my major gpa on my resume as just (GPA:#.#) as I had been under the impression that this was commonplace, and employees only wanted to know about coursework that is most relevant to the position. I'm now learning that it may not be.  My major gpa is .3 higher than my cumulative. Ive completed a background check and sent my transcripts (required of all employees) about a month ago now, and nothing has been brought up. The transcripts only list the cumulative gpa, the major gpa was calculated by me.

A degree wasn't even required for the position, so of course no listed GPA requirements. They were pretty clear about hiring me based on work experience, but i'm now worried that the discrepancy may be discovered and i'll be fired for being dishonest. I'm four years out of college and wish i had just left gpa off altogether to avoid all of this stress.

Should I address this with HR? Will that get me fired? Should I just quit and start looking elsewhere?

Comment: Please tag this with a location. Most answers make my hair stand on end for my part of the world, but since you mentioned "GPA" I think they are correct for your location. But only your location, this is not globally valid.

Comment: I asked a similar question, might help: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/114940/should-i-report-to-my-employer-that-my-resume-had-an-error-on-it

Comment: In which country are you? In most western countries, no one would care about your gpa, but only about your diplomas and experience. Especially if you are already working for the company and performing well (this should be your only concern right now). But some countries (ex: South Korea) focus a lot on the university you attended, your gpa and test scores (TOEIC,...)

Comment: 0.3 is such a small amount, no one is likely to care.  But it's such a small amount, why was it worth fudging it in the first place?

Comment: *"...and employees only wanted to know about coursework that is most relevant to the position...."* Did you mean employe**r**s?

Comment: GPAs lose importance as time passes, by a decade they mean nothing, and thus are usually not listed on more senior position's resumes.

Comment: A 0.3 difference isn't necessarily a small amount. Going from 2.5 to 2.8 is a small amount. Going from 3.7 to 4.0 is a much bigger deal, as is something like going from 2.8 to 3.1 when the job lists a 3.0 minimum.

Comment: I doubt employees care much one way or the other. Employers might be a little more concerned, but again, I doubt it would matter much. I'd be more concerned that a prospective candidate seemed unaware as to who was employing who!

Comment: I have no idea what a GPA is.

Comment: I've purposely put a bump of .3 to my overall GPA when applying to some jobs.  A portion of employers realize that grades aren't all that relevant, but it sure can help having a bit higher GPA for that portion that think it does matter.  The further removed from college and the more experience you have in a given field, the less it matters.

Answer (score 82):

This is almost certainly a non-issue. If it comes up clarify it then. Do not quit on the very off chance of you getting fired. Do not bring it up. Just do your job and do it well and I assure you they won't give a flying concern even if they do find out.

Comment: But do update your resume, either to say `(Major GPA: #.#)` or to list the total GPA that matches your transcript.  The term GPA, if it stands alone, does mean all-inclusive.

Answer (score 63):

You're four years out of college? Dude - nobody cares about your GPA anymore. Just leave it alone. Don't go to your boss, don't go to HR, don't mention it at all to anyone. Good, bad, or indifferent, nobody cares.

Comment: My PhD thesis is old enough to drink legally in the USA (so it’s older than 21 years). I was recently asked for my PhD transcripts! Some people do care! 

Comment: @fluffy That's ... really weird.

Comment: @fluffy "in the real world". No.

Comment: My present company asked for my college transcripts after 10 years after my graduating college.  One company always asked for my GPA even after 5 years of college.  Many business applications have fields for GPAs.

Comment: @JimClay Not weird for government, though. I applied for a government job a few years post graduating college and still had to submit my high school transcripts and ACT scores. Weird to require? Yes, but it's certainly consistent in government work. My guess is that they have all the requirements for lower level positions included in the requirements for higher positions as well.

Comment: My experience is that some people lie about having a degree (software) because they picked up coding as a hobby.  Transcripts are proof that the degree was indeed completed.  I have seen a guy hired based on previous job experience (and a resume saying he had a software degree) and then fired because he did not actually have the degree.

Comment: @Paul That's more often than not a symptom of bad HR. There are plenty of great coders who didn't go to school for it, but to get past the keyword filter that HR uses you have to say "BSc in Computer Science". I've had trouble with that, and I (am going to) have a Bachelor's, just in game design and development -- the HR people aren't familiar enough with the industry to realize that video game development is just a subcategory of software development.

Comment: @SandraK Apologies, I realize in retrospect how harmful my comment was. I have deleted it.

Answer (score 11):

If you're listing a GPA on a resume without any further qualification, it absolutely should be your overall GPA. You should fix your resume by either omitting your GPA entirely, changing the label to "Major GPA," or by changing the listed GPA to your overall one. Unless your GPA was particularly stellar, you're likely better off just omitting it entirely considering you already have 4+ years of work experience. No one is going to care about your GPA that much if you've already shown you're capable of doing the job well.

Having said all of that, since you already have 4+ years of experience and apparently have already been hired, it seems quite unlikely that anyone at your current job is going to care about this slip-up. In the unlikely event that someone ever does mention it, just tell them the truth: you listed your in-major GPA instead of your overall one under the mistaken impression that this was common practice. I see no point in bringing it up to your new employer at this point.

However, you really should fix it before applying for any future positions. Not listing your GPA on a resume is generally no big deal once you've been working for a while. Listing one that someone happens to notice is higher than your actual GPA, however, could cause a future hiring committee to think that you're being dishonest, which could lead them to drop you from further consideration without even telling you the reason.

Answer (score 9):

I would not worry. Your university likely does not disclose records to anyone just asking. Unless they ask you for your transcript they will not have access to your grades and in the unlikely case they do ask and bring it up, I would just explain it.

But again, the employers tend to not even verify your Alma mater.

Comment: OP stated that he sent transcripts.

Comment: They probably did not even look at it beyond "okay he was taking the major he mentioned at the uni he mentioned"

Answer (score 5):

Even if it is unusual to only list your GPA for your major, that is still your GPA for the major. It is not untrue, just ambiguous.

If you created the ambiguity intentionally then that would be dishonest, but that is another matter.

Comment: It was not dishonest at the time, because you assumed they would interpret it as your in-major GPA.  Now that you are aware that you were incorrect in that assumption, it *would* be dishonest to not clarify what you meant.  I doubt they'll care about a small difference in GPA, but you should inform them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If I was a hiring manager then this would sound off all sorts of red flags such as:

- Is dubma dishonest?
- Is dubma careless?
- If they misrepresented their GPA then what else have they misrepresented?
- Did dubma even attend this college?

You are now employed at a **financial** office and if I am not mistaken then they probably take accuracy very seriously.

---

Answer me truthfully:

If your "major" GPA was lower than cumulative then which number would you have used on your resume?

---

Never in my life have I heard of the idea of a "major" GPA and I switched majors twice. The poor performance of my early majors is reflected forever in my GPA.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion while employment of a job it is considered that what you have GPA on graduation, because at that time only your qualifications are degree and grading is what matters. You have already spent your four years , now onwards your performance in work center is only counted while awarding promotion and future  privileges.

I suggest while you have this weak point in your mind, you should not share it with your colleagues or your boss at all. You should give more attention towards your performance and try to get full grip on your assignment.  I am 100% sure, in case management came to know regarding your GPA, they will not fire you by analyzing your performance because for boss actually your performance is essential.

Answer (score -3):

If "a degree wasn't even required", whatever you told them about your GPA was irrelevant.

Telling lies about something that *is* relevant is a very bad idea, but in your case, most likely this was just "random noise" so far as the selection process was concerned - unless the selectors were wondering why someone with a degree was applying for the job when they were obviously over-qualified for it!

Comment: Not being a requirement does not mean it's irrelevant does it ?